# How do I get Eclipse to find and use a gcc based toolchain in a non-standard location

Tags: eclipse, gcc, embedded, cross-compiling, toolchain

I am trying to get Eclipse to work with a GCC based ARM cross compiler.

How can I configure eclipse to add the new tool chain to its list of tool chains?

The tool chain is a Raisonance distributed GCC tool chain:
C:\Program Files\Raisonance\Ride\arm-gcc\bin\arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to a pdf describing how to set up a cross compiler tool chain for ARM and eclipse.

http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorial/ARM/ARM_Cross_Development_with_Eclipse.pdf

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the command is you the PATH. Install [GNU ARM Eclipse Plug-in](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gnuarmeclipse/index.php?title=Main_Page), then you can choose the toolchain from a list.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, Raisonance's Ride uses the CodeSourcery toolchain. There are many tutorials out there on how to use it with Eclipse (at least for Helios). Last time I checked (last year), my Ride7 used the 2008 CodeSourcery compiler, though right now the latest version is 2011.03.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This really ought to have been a comment rather than an answer as it doesn't answer the question - but instead adds detail to other answers.